# Amplify for Govcloud?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, openid-connect, aws-amplify

Does AWS offer an authentication for Cognito that is compatible with react and gov cloud that is not Amplify. I am using Govcloud and my region is not in amplify(amplify does not support govcloud). How do I authenticate with OIDC and cognito via govcloud without amplify?

Answer (score 0):

I'll need some more details about your use case with OpenID Connect, but as far as authenticating with Cognito in a Gov Cloud region, use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js. It actually resides in the Amplify JS repository and is actively maintained.

Here is a basic example of logging in with a username and password.

```
const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool({
  UserPoolId: '...', // your user pool id here
  ClientId: '...'    // your client id here
})

function login(username, password) {
  const authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails({
    Username: username,
    Password: password,
  })
  
  const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser({
    Username: username,
    Pool: userPool,
  });

  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function(result) {
        const idToken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
        console.log(idToken);
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
  });
}
```

Also note, that when you add an app client to your User Pool, the `Generate client secret` option must be **unchecked** when creating a web app; the Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript doesn’t support apps that have a client secret simply because the client secret could be easily viewed in your code.